# VS Code 2017 F12 or Crtl Click Goto Definition not working, Angular 7.3.9

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular7

I am a beginner writing in Angular 7.3.9 I really need to use the the f12 function or ctrl right click to go to the definition. Currently it is not working. I am trying to uninstall and reinstall the code or is there any other way that guru out there can please shed some lights.

I have installed the following extension in the market place, is it because some of the extension is causing the problem?

[image: Go to Preference Keyboard Shortcuts]

It is already set to F12

aaron-bond.better-comments

alexiv.vscode-angular2-files

Angular.ng-template

christian-kohler.npm-intellisense

christian-kohler.path-intellisense

CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer

eamodio.gitlens

ecmel.vscode-html-css

EditorConfig.EditorConfig

eg2.vscode-npm-script

Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme

esbenp.prettier-vscode

formulahendry.auto-close-tag

formulahendry.auto-rename-tag

HookyQR.beautify

humao.rest-client

jchannon.csharpextensions

jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager

johnpapa.angular-essentials

johnpapa.Angular2

Metatype.copilot-vscode

miclo.sort-typescript-imports

Mikael.Angular-BeastCode

ms-azuretools.vscode-azureappservice

ms-vscode.azure-account

ms-vscode.csharp

ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin

msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome

nrwl.angular-console

oderwat.indent-rainbow

PKief.material-icon-theme

plibither8.remove-comments

pranaygp.vscode-css-peek

rbbit.typescript-hero

ritwickdey.live-sass

ritwickdey.LiveServer

spywhere.guides

steoates.autoimport

stringham.move-ts

Tyriar.sort-lines

vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag

WASTeamAccount.WebTemplateStudio-dev-nightly

Comment: You have to add the angular extension for the go to click event function definition

Comment: I have already added `loiane.angular-extension-pack` still it is not working, please help.